# How can I show GoogleMap v2 on Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I tried to show GoogleMap v2 in my Android application,but it failed.
Application didn't exit but I can't see GoogleMap on display as following image.
I got API key and set it in Android Manifest, and I did other settings for using GoogleMap v2.
For example, I added 7 permissions, 1 users-feature, 2 meta-data in Manifest.

Now I did nothing in MainActivity.java.(Just try to show main view.)

Is something missing for using it?
Is there anyone who has experience like this?
Please teach me how.

And I compiled it by Google API[Android 4.2.2]

Image URL : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88565794/2014-02-07%2023.15.21.png

Comment: check this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

Comment: Be sure to enable the API in the API console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this blog post, that describes almost the same problem:
http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2012/12/google-maps-android-api-v2-with-blank.html

> If you use Google Maps Android API v2, but with a blank (gray) map displayed, and "E/Google Maps Android API(12676): Authorization failure" reported in LogCat; may be caused by a wrong API Key assigned.

```
In order to use Maps Android API, you have to assign a API Key in AndroidManifest.xml.

     <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="your API Key here"/>
```

But there are many more sources availble that describe a similar problem: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=google+maps+v2+blank+map&client=safari

Ofcourse I can't tell you what you did wrong, but I would suggest you take a tutorail like this one:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ It even provides some how-to's on customization.

Or have a look at the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solve this! Actually the main problem is the way to install to my smartphone. First I make apk file and put it on Dropbox, and then I install it. I think this is bad way to use GoogleMap api, because after debugging application directly, success to show map.

Comment: Ok, so usb debugging over adb didn't work for you, perhaps you application has to be signed (non-dev) to use it. If my answered helped you, I would appreciate it if you click the green mark below the up/down vote button.

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing the app to your device from a different computer than the one you generated the debug key from? If so, you would need to add that debug key as well to you developer console settings.

I had this issue, maybe you're having the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I solve it as show in top answer's comment that I posted.